# Need assistance with doing redirect with variables without query string

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello:  I have some code in on file and it needs to redirect to a WP page and carry some variables with it.  Now I know I can do this with a "printf" statement and add some query string variables on the end of the URL of the page.  But I do not want the variables up in the URL.  I know if it was a form - it could be done with `GET` or `POST` variables.  And post variables are not up in the URL.  But the only way I know how to do post variables is with a form.  I cannot use a form for this that needs a "submit" button that needs to be pressed.  It needs to be something that is automatically executed when the script is loaded like a `printf` statement would be.  Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be done ?

Thanks,  Gerard

******* update 12/13 1:32PM EST ***************

Hello Arkascha - I have attempted to do what you suggested in your comment, and created the Curl call along with the post variables.  But it would not actually redirect to the page.  Not sure if I just did it wrong or if it cannot do that.  But i was researching and saw where people did a header redirect along with the CURL.  And so i thought i would try that.  What I have does do the redirect; but it does not seem to carry the post variables with it.  So I am not sure if something is wrong with my CURL code, or whether or not I need a header redirect.... etc etc...

here is my code:

```
$buy_refi='purchase'; 

$to_borrow=$entry["58"]; 
$home_worth=$entry["57"]; 
$down_payment=$entry["62"]; 
$purchase_price=$entry["54"]; 
$credit=$entry["15"];  

$data = array(
'buy_refi' => $buy_refi,
'to_borrow' => $to_borrow,
'home_worth' => $home_worth,
'down_payment' => $down_payment,
'purchase_price' => $purchase_price,
'credit' => $credit,
);

$data = http_build_query($data); // convert array to urlencoded string

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.mydomain.dev/purchase-options/', 
CURLOPT_POST => true,

));


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


curl_close($curl); 

header("Location:http://www.mydomain.dev/purchase-options/");
```

***********  here is the code on redirect page which will receive post variables...

```
$_POST['input_2']=$_POST['buy_refi'];
$_POST['input_58']=$_POST['to_borrow'];
$_POST['input_57']=$_POST['home_worth'];
$_POST['input_62']=$_POST['down_payment'];
$_POST['input_54']=$_POST['purchase_price'];
$_POST['input_15']=$_POST['credit'];


echo "post buy refi:  ".$_POST['buy_refi'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: Certainly that is possible. Take a look at phps `cURL` extension to make http `POST` requests: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php You will also find endless examples for that here on SO or out on google. Just take a look at a few.

Comment: thanks for commenting; i think I understand what you are saying; just want to confirm what you are saying; i want to go to a wordpress page url and carry post variables along with it; and it sounds like you are saying I can do that by just using curl like i do for a API call - but just put the WP page url as the endpoint - and I can add the post variables like "data" fields in the curl call; and then at the page - I can just receive the "post variables" as if it had come from a form?  If this is all correct that would be awesome... Please let me know if this is correct...

Comment: That certainly is correct. An API is nothing magical, it is simply a php script reacting to GET or POST variables. You can do the same in your wordpress script. If you are curious (which you should be...), then you can use a network sniffer to take a look at two POST requests: one sent by a html form, one sent by cURL.

Comment: Hello again arkascha:  I tried to cobble together what you suggested but could not get it to work, there could be a lot of things wrong with my code so really not sure, put it all up in the question as an update, if you could take a look and let me know what you think I would really appreciate it...

Comment: The post looks fine to me on first sight, though a bit chaotic. Might be the result of your various attempts :-) You can still clean that up later. Certainly those data values will get posted like that. However what I do _not_ understand is all that talk about "redirection". Why can't you simply post the values to the final processing destination?

Comment: Hello again:  let me try and explain this way, I am building a solution for a website located on wp-engine that does not allow session variables.  And i do not have total control over how all things are done as I am part of a team.  The boss has decided to use gravity forms (GF) which does not allow normal "post variables" to be passed like you can do with a simple html form.  So I am trying to work within the limits I am given.  The GF is located on WP page - and it needs to goto (or land) on another WP page and bring the variables with it. Normally GF can only send variables w/ query string.

Comment: What I am doing so far is i am using a "hook" to capture the input data from the GF.  this hook launches a function and is able to receive the inputs from the GF.  This function with hook is located in the theme's functions.php file.  So now I just need to somehow go to the second page and bring the input variables with it.  So essentially I am trying to leave that function and goto or "land" on the second WP page.  I just need the variables to be brought along; so on that second landing page the variables can be received and do stuff with them.  Does that help explain?  Thanks...

Comment: I have done some reading on this and a lot of people are saying Curl cannot actually redirect to another page and bring the variables with it.  But you may know better.  But I think what I have right now are two seperate pieces, the Curl code which does not redirect, and the header redirect that does not carry any values with it.  So I could use some help on this if you know the Curl can redirect and can see why my code is not...

Comment: Sorry, as mentioned before I do not understand why you have to redirect. Without that I cannot say anything.

Comment: Hello Arkascha:  I am not sure I need to do the "header redirect".  What I need is this:  while it is in the function in the theme file, I need it to gather the inputs from form and then "redirect" or "move" to a "destination" wordpress page.  So it needs to bring the input variables along with it when it goes.  I was hoping the Curl code would do all of that, but what I have does not redirect or "move" to the second page.  So I added the header redirect because I read in some places that had to be done.  But if that is unneeded ...

Comment: If that is unneeded - then I need to know how to make my Curl code do the redirect itself...I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97868/gman-donster-and-arkascha

Comment: I still have problems to understand the base of this. You try to explain how you think you might be able to achieve what you are looking for. Why don't you instead try to explain what it is (what, not how) you want to achieve. Then it might be much easier for others to follow. I can imagine three scenarios:

Comment: 1. you have a page and want to redirect the user somewhere else whilst taking along some values. I don't see why you cannot use a form here. A form does not need a submit button, you can send it in background or foreground by means of ajax.

Comment: 2. you have a user on your page, some request is sent to your server side, some processing takes place and now you want to forward the user to some other location taking along some values from the previous processing. Again you can use a form, but what for? If you are still talking about locations on the same system, then why forward those values at all? You already have them on your system. Just store them, redirect, and re-read the values wherever you stored them.

Comment: 3. you have _two_ separate pages that do not share a storage option. In that case indeed you need to post the values. You can use cURL for that. On the receiving site you store or process the posted values. Now you make a header redirect to forward the use to the other site where you posted the values to. There you can re-read the values or processed values where you stored them to after having received them.

Comment: As said above: try to describe what it is you want to achieve. Not how you might be able to, or how "it" does something "in some function". That only confuses. Talk about a user experience. Explain your setup and service. Tell what is missing exactly.

Comment: Hello Arkascha:  did you want to move this to chat?  A link came up - not sure if that was automatically put there by stackoverflow - or if you triggered that...

Comment: I triggered it manually, I am waiting there, you joined, I communicated. All you have to do is reply.